# dataframe to save csv: not accumulating the records only saving the last dataframe group records

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops, webdriver

dataframe question in web scraping data group
example:the first loop-eg:5 records, second loop-eg:3 records
when I did my below code, the csv file was saved the second loop group without stacking from the first loop group records. please advise me.

```
df=[] 
for i in range(1,3,1):
    state=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//select[@name='state']")
    stateDD=Select(state)
    stateDD.select_by_index(i)
    time.sleep(3)
    print(f'Getting page, {i}')
 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'lxml')
    
    data=[]
    for card in soup.select('#resultscontainer > ul > li > div.repcontent'):
        state = i
        company = card.select_one('h3.company_title').text
        #print(company)
        address = card.select_one('div.address').text
        address2 = card.select_one('div.address2').text
        try:
            phone = card.select('span')[0].text
        except IndexError:
            phone = ""
        try:
            fax = card.select('span')[1].text
        except IndexError:
            fax = "" 
        data.append({
            'state': state,
            'company':company,
            'address':address,
            'address2':address2,
            'phone':phone,
            'fax':fax
            })
        
    #print(data)
 
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        #print(df.head())
        df.to_csv('D:/92Python/Output/gastite.csv', index=False)
driver.close
```

Comment: `data` seems like a list of dict, you'd better use `pd.DataFrame(data)` to create dataframe. If you want to merge the loops data, you may declare `data=[]` outside of the loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot. still not solved. if I use mode='a' in df.to_csv(xxx.csv, mode='a', index=False, header=False), records are saving duplicated.